# Nginx doesn't execute PHP

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx, phpbb, phpbb3

I really need help with Nginx on my Ubuntu Server. I set up Nginx normally and everything works so far. That means if I put an index.html into `/var/www/mydomain.com/public_html` it works just fine.

But now I wanted to install phpBB there. I followed the tutorial and extracted it in the `public_html` folder. I got a folder called "phpBB3" so I went to my browser to mydomain.com/phpBB3 as the tutorial said.

But the PHP did not execute. It tried to download an `"application/octet-stream"` file. I opened the file in notepad and it turned out to be the PHP script.

I have no idea what to do. Yes, PHP is installed and yes, I looked on google and StackOverflow and followed the instructions. But nothing seemed to help. So please don't just mark this as duplicate and post a link to another StackOverflow question. Because I already tried that and it won't really help me.

My configs are as follows:

`/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`
http://pastebin.com/rUbHybDD

`/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini`

http://pastebin.com/HeynV4Je

This is really important to me, thank you!

Comment: Really? No one can help me?

Comment: You throw in several different configs into one. How you think that works? In your php-fpm config, there is in the same file your nginx config. It won't work lol. php.ini, php-fpm config and nginx config must be 3 different files.

Comment: They are different files

Comment: You have nginx config in the php.ini file..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found out why it didn't work. The thing is I have two configs in the sites-aviable directory. First one is "default" and second one is "mydomain.com". I appied all changes to the "default" config while I left the "mydomain.com" config untouched. And that was the problem. I had to apply all changes to the "mydomain.com" config aswell.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing: (In `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`)

```
location ~ \.php$ {
try_files $uri =404;
fastcgi_pass unix:/tmp/php.socket;
fastcgi_index index.php;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
include fastcgi_params;
}
```

By:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work :/
Could it be that it has something to do with the line 
`"root /usr/share/nginx/html;"` since my real html root is `/var/www/domain.com/public_html`?

Comment: Yes, can be that, replace the route `root /usr/share/nginx/html;` by `root /var/www/domain.com/public_html;`

Comment: Nope, nothing changed. But I tried something: I opened the website (mydomain.com/phpBB3) in internet explorer in stead or firefox. Internet explorer doesnt download the file like firefox, but displays the php as plain text.

Comment: PHP is not loading, did you use the `sudo service nginx restart` command after modifying what I told you? If you did not use it, run it.

Comment: And check if php5-fpm.sock is in `/var/run/php5-fpm.sock`

Comment: Yes, I restarted nginx and php aswell.
Still doesnt work. Even after a restart of the whole server.
And yea there is a `php5-fpm.sock` file
I have no idea where the cause of the problem is. I really need to get that forum up